# Objects as input of a form in Play framework

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.0

All the examples of models and forms of the Play framework (I use 2.0.4) use `String`, `int` or `Long` as attributes.

However I have a model like this:

```
public class MyModel {

    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    public Date birthdate;

    @Required
    public MyClass someObject;    
}
```

Now for the `name` I can simply use a `@inputText(...)` field in my form.

For the `birthDate` I tried using an `@inputDate(...)` field in my form, but this just gives me an input field and whatever format of date I try to enter in the input field, it gets rejected. I also tried passing `'format -> "dd/mm/yyyy"` to this field, without success.

I don't even know how I can possibly enter a `MyClass` object for the form.

1. How can I make the `@inputDate()` work?
2. Is it necessary to make
   every input a String/Int/Long and upon receiving those values in the controller to
   construct a `MyClass` object of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer for question number (1).

You may consider this technique. The model might be like below:

```
@Required
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date birthdate;
```

So, you can make your view as simple as:

```
@helper.inputDate(myForm("birthdate"), '_label -> "Birthdate", '_help -> "format dd/MM/yyy")
```

#### Answer for question number (2).

As far as I know, it is a must to have submitted value from HTML form in the form of `String`, `Int`, `Long`. Because they are the common format to display information on screen. Additionally, HTML input value is represented in `String`, 'Int', 'Long' type.

---

FYI, there is useful sample like `computer-database` a you can learn for **model** that connected to other class. It is located at `<PlayFrameworkInstallDirectory>/samples/java/computer-database`.